# Resolve: $\ddot{x_1}=2x_1-3x_2, \ddot{x_2}=x_1-2x_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

**Resolve:   $\ddot{x_1}=2x_1-3x_2,  \ddot{x_2}=x_1-2x_2$**

I have to $\ddot{x}=\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x_1}\\ \ddot{x_2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -3\\1 & -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{pmatrix}=Ax$ and I know that for a $\dot{x}=Ax$ system the solution is given by $x=e^{At}x_0$, I just know how to apply this to this system, I thought to do the following:

I have to $\ddot{x}=Ax$, could you say that $\dot{x}=e^{At}x_0$ and so $x=e^{e^At}x_0$? Or I have thought of linearizing the system and I already found that $\bar{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ is equilibrium point and so to solve $\ddot{x}=Ax$, I can solve $\ddot{x}=D_f(\bar{x})x$ and in this way how would I do?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reduce to a first-order system: let $y_1 := x_1$, $y_2 := \dot x_1$, $y_3 := x_2$, $y_4 := \dot x_2$, so the first-order system is $\dot y_1 = y_2$, $\dot y_2 = 2 y_1 - 3 y_3$, $\dot y_3 = y_4$, $\dot y_4 = y_1 - 2 y_3$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Please do not post answers as comments.

Comment: "I have to $\ddot{x}=Ax$, could you say that $\dot{x}=e^{At}x_0$ and so $x=e^{e^At}x_0$?" No, one cannot. To see why this idea is unsound, one can try it on the one-dimensional case $$\ddot z=z$$ Then you predict that $$\dot z(t)=e^tz_0$$ which is obviously wrong since the general solution of $\ddot z=z$ is a linear combination $$z(t)=Ce^t+C'e^{-t}$$ for which, as soon as $C'\ne0$, $$\dot z(t)=Ce^t-C'e^{-t}\ne (C+C')e^t=e^tz_0$$